# After Updating Windows 10, Network Drives Cannot Connect After Reboot

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, samba

After a recent Windows 10 update, my network drive shares from Windows to Samba shares no longer work after reboot.

I have two shared drives which live on my Linux Samba server: `Z:` is my home directory, and `X:` is a shared drive for all my users.

After reboot, when I try to access `Z:` or `X:` I get the following error:

[image]

As a temporary fix, I open Command Prompt and type `net use z: /delete` and `net use x: /delete`, then in Windows Explorer, I can re-create the mapped drives. I am checking the box that says, "Reconnect at sign-in". It stays working until the next reboot, then the same error appears when trying to access `z:` or `x:`. It gets annoying destroying and re-creating the mapped drive letters after each reboot.

I suspect this has something to do with two separate drive letters mapped to the same Samba server but two different shares.  Or perhaps an incompatibility with older versions of Samba? I have a third network drive, `v:`, mapped to one share on a separate newer Samba server, which works fine after every reboot.

There are no physical drives mapped to these drive letters (drive letters `C:` through `H:` are mapped to drives and SD card readers).  I confirmed this in the Disk Management tool.

This started after I upgraded Windows 10 Pro to version 10.0.19041

Comment: What' your system OS build? Type "winver" to check. The latest security update refers to October 1, 2020—KB4577063 (OS Build 19041.546) Preview. Remap works only before restart， try to check the registry below: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
Delete MountPoints2 Value

Comment: `Version 2004 (OS Build 19041.508)`. I do not have a `MountPoints2` in the registry folder you specified.

Comment: I was able to find a workaround by choosing to SAVE my username/password when creating the mapping of the drive to the share.  Now, it does reconnect to `x:` and `z:` after reboot.  I am annoyed that I had to store my Samba server password in Windows, which I never had to do before and I preferred being prompted after reboot for security reasons, but at least reconnecting does work after each reboot now.